# adding the sum of a digit using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to add the sum of a given digit i.e 1234 the sum is 10
this is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim number As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim sum As Integer
    number = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    While (number <> 0)
        r = number Mod 10
        sum = sum + r
        number = number / 10
    End While
    Label3.Text = sum
End Sub
```

but when i input 123456 it gives me 24 instead of 21, whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Use number = number \ 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation `number / 10` uses regular division, which converts each number to a floating-point value, divides, and then coerces (rounds) the result back into an integer so it can be stored in `number` again.  With the input `123456`, after the first time through the loop, the new value of number is `12346` instead of `12345` as it should be.

Instead, you need to use `number \ 10`, which performs integer division and does not round.

More information on VB operators [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This line `number = number / 10` should be   `number = number \ 10`

Answer (score 0):

Sub Main()
        Console.Title = ("Sum of digits calculator")
        Dim x, sum As Double
        x = InputBox("Enter any number : ")
        sum = 0

```
    While x > 0
        sum += x Mod 10
        x = (x / 10) - ((x Mod 10) / 10)

    End While
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of digits = " & sum)
    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```